# Span Image over two Columns without Perturbing the Text Flow

Tags: graphics, floats, two-column

I would like to insert an image into a two-column document, but have the text flow around the image, avoiding to perturb the text flow, like shown here:

[image]

I tried to do it with the option "strip" from the package "cuted", but it is not working so far.

Here is a demo code to play with:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{caption} %to insert a caption
\usepackage{lipsum}  %for dummy text
\usepackage{todonotes} %for dummy figure

\usepackage{cuted} %main package: to insert the image 

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\section{Introduction}
%some text
\lipsum[2-4]
%place the figure
\begin{strip}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-golden}
    \captionof{figure}{label}
    \label{fig:python_convergence_reflection}
    \end{figure}
\end{strip}
%some more text
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

However, I get the error:

> Float(s) lost

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why do you put a float environment (`\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`) inside the `strip`?

Comment: @DG' I just tried that. Is this wrong ? How would you do it ? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the `figure` environment. `strip` is *not* a floating environment, and that's why `\captionof{figure}` is used, instead of `\caption`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The floats are lost, because they are nested inside the `strip`, the `strip` environment is a *replacement* of `figure`, not an addition to it. And since you don't want them to float you just have to remove the lines containing `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{caption} %to insert a caption
\usepackage{lipsum}  %for dummy text
\usepackage{todonotes} %for dummy figure

\usepackage{cuted} %main package: to insert the image

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\section{Introduction}
%some text
\lipsum[2-4]
%place the figure
\begin{strip}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-golden}
    \captionof{figure}{label}
    \label{fig:python_convergence_reflection}
\end{strip}
%some more text
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the desired text flow use `midfloat` instead of `cuted`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{caption} %to insert a caption
\usepackage{lipsum}  %for dummy text
\usepackage{todonotes} %for dummy figure

\usepackage{midfloat} %main package: to insert the image

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\section{Introduction}
%some text
\lipsum[1]
%place the figure
\begin{strip}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-golden}
    \captionof{figure}{label}
    \label{fig:python_convergence_reflection}
\end{strip}
%some more text
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Would you also know how to have the text continue, as if the image was not there (see Image in Question)?... i.e the text above the image should not continue in the second column but in the first column.

Comment: Use `midfloat` instead of `cuted`

Comment: Yes !! This works. Thank you so much for your great help! :))